# How do I get css background image to show in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am attempting to learn and use Angular.  My dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
```

And I have the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<div id='wrapper'>
                <div id='header'></div>
                <div id='logo'></div>
                {{name}}
           </div>`,
styleUrls: ['./src/app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

and the following css in the above referenced file:

```
#wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: -30px;
}

#header {
background: url(/Content/Images/cover_background.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

#logo {
width: 252px;
height: 207px;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 150px;
padding-bottom: 150px;
background: url(/Content/Images/logo_square_white.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

Given all of that, when the page renders, all the space for the images is allocated.  When I view the network traffic in Chrome developer tools, I see the images load with a 200 OK.  I can even click on the image in developer tools and see them.  But on the screen, there is only a blank page where the image goes.

The text 'Angular' displays in the correct location.  Only the background images are missing.

In the developer tools I disabled the browser cache.

How do I get my background CSS images to show up in my Angular component?

Comment: could you provide an working example of the issue?

Comment: Just riffing here: Have you tried `background-image` instead of `background`? And `#header` has no content in the DOM and no defined height in the CSS, so regardless, nothing will display there.

Comment: @SteveG. That did the trick.  I guess I need 'background-image' instead of just 'background' when using Angular.  It did not need '-image' for straight HTML.  Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Well really, it shouldn't make a difference with Angular. Don't know the exact problem you were encountering, but I just suggested adding `-image` for debugging. Its working your original way in this Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mtYD40KradadfzHCiGlv?p=preview (I did have to set a height to your `#header` element, but that shouldn't have made a difference with `#logo`.) Either way, glad it's working for you!